# classification model with low inference time

Tags: deep-learning

Could anyone suggest a classification model with inference time may be less than a second?

I have trained mobile net and squeeze net but both take around 2 secs for a single image inference.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The speed depends on the hardware specifications. To run this model even faster, you can try installing 'OpenVino' (works only for intel hardware), which helps to run the model 3x faster. Refer the below comparison from Intel.

[Performance improvement using Openvino software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0SPc.png)

You have free version of 'Openvino' for CPU. This software works even for GPU inbuilt devices.

Check more details in the below link:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/openvino-toolkit